# OpenStreetMap XML

Tags: xml, openstreetmap

I am fairly new to openstreetmap and hence this question.
Is there a way to download an extract (XML file) of openstreetmap for a specific region or country, containing all data. For instance, on the website when i select a road, i can export an XML file including object information such as the maxspeed (see link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/101255073). However if I try to export a whole region it doesnt contain any object information. Btw I want to have this locally on my pc. So with queries to any api.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

The complete OSM data is called [Planet.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm). You can either download the whole file or smaller [country and area extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). Also read the [technical notes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Technical_notes) about how to process this data.

You can also download filtered data by using [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API), e.g if your are only interested in roads or buildings. However, depending on the query, this will only work for small to medium areas and not for the whole world (except for simple queries with small results).